# General continuity rule for a rational function of two variabales.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

$f(x,y) = \frac{x^my^n}{x^i+y^j}$ is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ if and only if (iff) $mj+ni>ij$. I tried the approach $\frac{m}{i}$ + $\frac{n}{j}$ >1, but its of no use. Any other approach I should try?
It is given $f(0,0) = 0$.
It is also given m,n are non-negative integers and i,j are even natural numbers.

Comment: Is that what you required ?

Comment: I am just trying an approach to prove the continuity of the function. I guessed the powers are making a good pattern, but I got stuck with that approach.

Comment: You could add to the problem that $i, j, m, n > 0$ perhaps. To prove that the condition is necessary, take $x=t^j$ and $y=t^i$. You may need to add that $i$ and $j$ are even because $\frac{xy}{x+y}$ is not continuous at $(0, 0)$ for example

Comment: Yes, in my haste I forgot to mention that m and n are non-negative integers while i and j are even natural numbers. Thank you for bringing this into my notice @Gribouillis

Comment: Thank you @Gribouillis, your advice helped me solve it.

Comment: If you solved it, you could perhaps post an answer for everybody to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u, v, a, b >0$ one has
\begin{equation}
\frac{u^a v^b}{(u+v)^{(a + b)}} \le \frac{a^a b^b}{(a+b)^{(a + b)}}\equiv C(a,b)
\end{equation}
Indeed, this is just a convexity inquality for the concave function $\ln$
\begin{equation}
\theta \ln\left(\frac{u}{a}\right) + (1-\theta)\ln\left(\frac{v}{b}\right)\le \ln\left(\theta \frac{u}{a} + (1-\theta)\frac{v}{b}\right),\qquad \theta=\frac{a}{a+b}
\end{equation}
Assuming $i, j\in 2 {\mathbb{N}^*}$, and applying this to $u=x^i$ and $v=y^j$ and $a=m/i$ and $b = n/j$ yields
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{x^m y^n}{x^i+y^j}\right|\le C\left(\frac{m}{i},\frac{n}{j}\right)
(x^i+y^j)^{\frac{m}{i}+\frac{n}{j}-1}
\end{equation}
Thus, if $\frac{m}{i}+\frac{n}{j}>1$, the right hand side tends to $0$ when $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$ and so does $f(x, y)$.

Conversely if $f(x, y)\to 0$, then
\begin{equation}
0 = \lim_{t\to 0 ^+} f(t^j, t^i) = \lim_{t\to 0 ^+}\frac{1}{2} t^{m j + n i - ij}
\end{equation}
hence $m j + n i - i j > 0$, which is equivalent to $\frac{m}{i}+\frac{n}{j}>1$.

**Edit:** I found that there is an even more direct way
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[l]\
|x|^m=(x^i)^{m/i}\le (x^i + y^j)^{m/i}\cr
|y|^n=(y^j)^{n/j}\le (x^i + y^j)^{n/j}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Hence $|f(x,y)|\le (x^i+y^j)^{\frac{m}{i}+\frac{n}{j}-1}$

Comment: If you could explain the concept of convexity inequality, it would be helpful for me

Comment: @ARIJITSINGH Have a look at [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) and [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Note that $\ln$ is a concave function, or equivalently its opposite $-\ln$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Firstly, we show that
$f$ is continuous at $(0,0) \Rightarrow mj+ni>ij$.
There exists $(x_k,y_k)$ such that $(x_k,y_k) \to (0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(x_k,y_k) \to f(0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$.
Therefore, $f(x_k,y_k) = \frac{x_k^my_k^n}{x_k^i+y_k^j}$.
Let there exist $t_k$ such that $t_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
And $x_k = t_k^j$ and $y_k=t_k^i$.
Putting this value in $f(x_k,y_k)$, we get
$f(t_k^j,t_k^i) = \frac{t_k^(mj)t_k^(ni)}{t_k^(ij)+t_k^(ij)}$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(t_k^j,t_k^i) = \frac{t_k^(mj+ni)}{2t_k^(ij)}$.
Now, $f(x_k,y_k) \to f(0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(t_k^j,t_k^i) \to f(0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{t_k^(mj+ni)}{2t_k^(ij)} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $|\frac{t_k^(mj+ni)}{2t_k^(ij)}| \le |t_k^\alpha|$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.
Now, for the continuity to be satisfied, we need $\alpha \gt 1$.
Thus, $mj+ni \gt ij$

(2)Secondly, we show that
$mj+ni>ij$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.
There exists $(x_k,y_k)$ such that $(x_k,y_k) \to (0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$.
And, $f(x_k,y_k) = \frac{x_k^my_k^n}{x_k^i+y_k^j}$.
Let there exist $t_k$ such that $t_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
And $x_k = t_k^j$ and $y_k=t_k^i$.
Putting this value in $f(x_k,y_k)$, we get
$f(t_k^j,t_k^i) = \frac{t_k^(mj)t_k^(ni)}{t_k^(ij)+t_k^(ij)}$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(t_k^j,t_k^i) = \frac{t_k^(mj+ni)}{2t_k^(ij)}$.
Since, $mj+ni>ij$
$\Rightarrow$ $|\frac{t_k^(mj+ni)}{2t_k^(ij)}| \le |t_k^\alpha|$ for some $\alpha \in (1,\infty)$.
Since $t_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(t_k^j,t_k^i) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(x_k,y_k) \to f(0,0)$ as $k \to \infty$
$\Rightarrow$ $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow mj+ni>ij$